# Is "phobophobia" a paradoxical word?

Tags: meaning

Is "***phobophobia***" a misnomer? Phobophobia is a fear of fears or the sensations relating to them. However, if somebody has phobophobia, they will be scared of phobophobia, since it is a phobia itself. So, if makes it ***phobophobophobia***, and this will go on forever and ever. So, is the name "***Phobophobia***" a paradoxical misnomer?

Comment: ***It is a real pathology, no paradox***: *Described as a fear of phobias, Phobophobia is literally defined as a fear of fears. This may include the fear of getting diagnosed with a phobia, hearing or learning about phobias, or just an overwhelming sense of terror.* Symptoms affecting those with phobophobia are commonly found across many other phobias and anxiety disorders. When placed in a stressful situation or during a panic attack a sufferer may experience. https://www.allaboutcounseling.com/library/phobophobia/

Comment: I'm afraid it might be.

Comment: President Roosevelt said the only thing we have to fear is fear itself, so, for him,  phobophobia was the only phobia,

Comment: @davidlol You are true to your name (**lol**)

Comment: @Josh Like you said - *Described as a fear of phobias*. That in itself is paradoxical. If somebody is afraid of a fear, they must be afraid of that fear of a fear, and so on and so forth, making it a paradox.

Comment: @Emereal - I don't see the paradox, and the term has actually a wider connotation. I suggest you read the whole definition in medical texts.

Comment: @Josh I mean if there is a fear of a *fear*, then there must be a ***fear*** of that *fear* of the **fear**. Then, there must be a fear of that fear of the fear of the fear, and so on. That's what makes it paradoxical.

Comment: Your logic is hurting my head. Having this phobia does not mean a fear of all phobias. You cannot attribute pure rationality to irrational feelings..

Comment: @YosefBaskin That's not what I mean. I mean if phobophobia is a fear of phobias, then wouldn't they also be afraid if phobophobia, if phobophobia in itself is a fear?

Comment: @Emereal - that is a syllogism, not a paradox.

Comment: "phobophobophobia" is a phobia, too, hence by definition phobophobia covers it as well, along with all other "(phobo*∞)phobias"

Comment: Having this phobia does not mean a fear of all phobias. While that would be logical, those who suffer with this phobia are not using logic when overpowered by their fears.

Comment: Ah; I see now. I thought phobophobia could apply to itself ∞ times.

Comment: Well, the last time I visited my doc and told him I thought I might be a hypochondriac, he said: "Of course you're not, you just think you are".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's answer these two questions serially.

### Is "phobophobia" a paradox?

A [paradox](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/paradox) is:

> 1. a statement or proposition that seems self-contradictory or absurd but in reality expresses a possible truth.
> 2. a self-contradictory and false proposition.

A fear of fear *may seem* self-contradictory on the surface. But as @Josh pointed out in his comments, this *may include the fear of getting diagnosed with a phobia, hearing or learning about phobias*. Just as one can fear being diagnosed with cancer, there is no self-contradiction that one can fear being diagnosed with a phobia. Neither is it absurd. Neither is *phobophobia* a false (logical) proposition.

In response to the title: No, not a paradox.

### Is "phobophobia" a misnomer?

The OP said,

> if somebody has phobophobia, they will be scared of phobophobia, since it is a phobia itself.

I disagree; the OP may be confusing phobophobia with [panphobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panphobia).

> The term panphobia was first coined by Théodule-Armand Ribot in his 1911 work *The Psychology of the Emotions*. He defined it as "a state in which a patient fears everything or nothing, where anxiety, instead of being riveted on one object, floats as in a dream, and only becomes fixed for an instant at a time, passing from one object to another, as circumstances may determine."

There is no misnomer here. Say that someone has a fear of cats, ailurophobia. If she does not want to be diagnosed with ailurophobia, or hearing about an ailurophobia support group, then *in addition to* fearing cats, she has phobophobia.

In response to the main question: No, not a misnomer.